# Why cant I use these rational, numerator & denominator from class numbers.Rational in Python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, numbers, python-3.8, rational-number

**Can someone help me in understanding how to use these rational, numerator & denominator**

*class numbers.Rational
Subtypes Real and adds numerator and denominator properties, which should be in lowest terms. With these, it provides a default for float().

numerator
Abstract.

denominator
Abstract.*

[Here's the link to the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Rational)

[Here's the link to official code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/numbers.py)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numbers` module provides some *abstract base classes* that you can use if you are implementing your own numeric types. You don't *need* to use them, but they offer some help in getting things right, if you want it.

They're not builtin types that you can always access, those are different. The concrete numeric types in Python are `int`, `float`, `complex` and, if you're willing to go into the standard library, `fractions.Fraction` and `decimal.Decimal`.

In the interactive session you show in the question, you're creating a `complex` object and a `float` (by dividing integers). These are not the same thing as `numbers.Complex` or `numbers.Rational`. And while the `numbers.Complex` class's API is a close match to how the concrete `complex` type actually works, the `float` type is much more different from the abstract `numbers.Rational` API.

If you just want to represent a `float` as a fraction, try calling the [`as_integer_ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.as_integer_ratio) method on it. This may not be the fraction you expect! That's because floating point values are not always exact, especially when a binary representation was infinitely repeating and needed to be truncated somewhere.

Comment: Can't I use rational in some way or other as I used complex??? Then what's the benefit of that class??

Comment: @ShambhavAgrawal: The `fractions.Fraction` class has the API required by the `numbers.Rational` abstract base class, so you can use it if you want `numerator` and `denominator`. As I say in the answer, you only need to use `numbers` if you are implementing your own numeric types. You *might* use it to check for certain number-like APIs, but the builtin types don't reliably use them, so I'd not bother.